# Does using const global vars instead of enum ensure ABI compatibility?

Tags: c, abi

In a C library project of mine I have an enum that lists all possible types a piece of data handled by the library can be:

```
// lib.h
enum types {
    VOID,
    INT,
    FLOAT,
    CONST_INT,
    CONST_FLOAT
}
```

The code will be compiled into a shared library. In future versions of the library, I will be required to insert new entries into the enum and reorder existing ones. AFAIK this breaks ABI compatibility since the enum is not transformed into a set of symbols that ends up in the library, but rather causes whatever integer the compiler assigns to each entry to be hardcoded. Is that the case?

If so, would it be preferable to instead use constant global variables such that they make an appearance in the symbol table and I thus can change both order and the value assigned to each?

```
// lib.c
const int VOID = 1;
const int INT = 2;
const int FLOAT = 3;
const int CONST_INT = 4;
const int CONST_FLOAT = 5;

// lib.h
extern const int VOID;
extern const int INT;
extern const int FLOAT;
extern const int CONST_INT;
extern const int CONST_FLOAT;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. If you plan to expand the enumered variables it could make incompatible the future versions of your libraries.
If you take a look to some of the most relevant sw around (i.e. MS or linux headers) you can see that the solutions adopted are mainly two:

1. Use defines
2. Still use enum, but assign a value per each entry

The latter makes the use of enum quite equal to defines, but retains the properties of enums.
In your case it could be:

```
// lib.h
enum types {
    VOID = 0,
    INT = 1,
    FLOAT = 10,
    CONST_INT = 12,
    CONST_FLOAT = 13
}
```

Then when in future you will add other codes:

```
// lib.h
enum types {
    VOID = 0,
    INT = 1,
    CUSTOM1 = 3,
    FLOAT = 10,
    CUSTOM2 = 11,
    CONST_INT = 12,
    CONST_FLOAT = 13,
    CUSTOM4 = 20
}
```

The use of constant globals could have some problems, even to be optimized out and be replaced by constants.

Comment: Beware that adding entries to an enumeration changes the type and may yield a larger integer type for storing the enum variables, which is why you occasionally see large/negative reserved padding entries for future-proofing. Admittedly in practice this is mostly an issue on 8-bit ABIs, especially for consecutive enumerations.

Comment: @doynax a solution to that is to use `int` as the type of any variable which will hold one of these enumerators. (All enumerators are `int` regardless of the underlying type of the enum)

Comment: @M.M: That is indeed the most frequent workaround. Kind of annoying not receiving any assistance from the debugger in deciphering the values though.

Answer (score 0):

best way is to place the enum in the header file for that library.

Changing the enum will still require re-compiling/linking etc of the library (no getting around that),

To assure each label in the enum has the specific value, the enum can be written similar to:

```
enum 
{
    label1 = 0,
    label2 = 1,
    label3 = 20,
    label4 = 5
};
```

the results in anonymous enum, where each of the labels are visible and have the appropriate value.